# criticality for nonlinear wave equations on manifolds

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, manifolds, wave-equation

On $\mathbb{R}^{1+n}$, the initial value problem for the homogeneous wave equation

$$ \Box \phi = \partial_t^2 \phi - \Delta_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi = 0, \\ (\phi, \partial_t \phi)|_{t=0} = (\phi_0, \phi_1) \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \times H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n) $$

exhibits the scaling symmetry $\phi(t,x) \mapsto \phi_\lambda(t,x) = \phi(\lambda t, \lambda x)$,

$$ \Box \phi_\lambda = 0, \\ (\phi_\lambda, \partial_t \phi_\lambda)|_{t=0} = (\phi_0^\lambda, \lambda \phi_1^\lambda ), $$

where $\phi_i^\lambda(x) = \phi_i(\lambda x)$. The $\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ norm of $\phi$ scales with $\lambda$ as

$$ \| \phi_i^\lambda \|_{\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \lambda^{s - \frac{n}{2}} \| \phi_i \|_{\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}, $$

which leads to the conclusion that the exponent $s = \frac{n}{2}$ is scaling-critical, i.e. for $s > \frac{n}{2}$ one can trade size of initial data against time of existence of the solution. When the equation is non-linear, proving existence below scaling criticality is therefore frequently hard or impossible (a specific example is wave maps, where there is ill-posedness for $s < \frac{n}{2}$).

My question is what happens instead if I consider wave equations on non-flat backgrounds, in particular on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^n$,

$$ \partial_t^2 \psi - \Delta_{\mathbb{S}^n} \psi = 0, \\ (\psi, \partial_t \psi)|_{t=0} = (\psi_0, \psi_1) \in H^s(\mathbb{S}^n) \times H^{s-1}(\mathbb{S}^n). $$

**Q1:** As far as I can see there is no analogue of the scaling symmetry in this case since $\mathbb{S}^n$ is not a vector space: **is this true?**

**Q2:** If, so, how does one access the critical exponent in this case? (I would expect nonlinear equations on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^n$ to fail to be well-posed below criticality). Is the relationship with Sobolev embedding $H^s(\mathbb{S}^n) \hookrightarrow C^0(\mathbb{S}^n)$ for $s > \frac{n}{2}$ all that remains?